# What is subscriberHash parameter in deleteListMember method of mailchimp-marketing plugin?

Tags: laravel, mailchimp

When I need to add in laravel 10 app user to mailchimp I use addListMember method of https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php (v3.0) plugin

```
    $response = $this->getApiClient()->lists->addListMember($this->mailchimpListId, [
        "email_address" => $email,
        "status" => "subscribed",
        'merge_fields' => $userMergeFields,
    ]);
    \Log::info(varDump($response, ' -1 subscribe $response::'));
```

It returns structure like :

```
Array
(
    [id] => 79847477e940c304958adadc24e52312
    [email_address] => JohnDoe@site.com
    [unique_email_id] => 56ed730de7
    [contact_id] => 7e4dc0052b2bae88c8c914d34e5170d9
    [full_name] => John Doe
    [web_id] => 292542436
    [email_type] => html
    [status] => subscribed
    [consents_to_one_to_one_messaging] => 1
    [sms_phone_number] =>
    [sms_subscription_status] =>
    [sms_subscription_last_updated] =>
    [merge_fields] => stdClass Object
```

But when I need to unsubscribe user I use method deleteListMember, but it has 2nd parameter subscriber_hash. I tried to pass value of any of the fields
id, unique_email_id, contact_id, web_id values  from response above

But in all cases I got 404 error :

```
The requested resource could not be found
```

Also I searched and did not find any parameter like subscriber_hash under mailchimp user properties :

[image]

Searching in net I found some hints that method subscriberHash of mailchimp can be used- but I did not any similar function in the library by packages.

How can I get this subscriberHash value ?

**ATTEMPT TO FIX:**
I modified my code as

```
$response = $this->getApiClient()->lists->deleteListMember($email, md5(strtolower($email)));
```

But anyway I got 404 error :

```
    The requested resource could not be found.
```

What can be wrong ?

Comment: From the docs: `subscriber_hash` > "The MD5 hash of the lowercase version of the list member's email address. This endpoint also accepts a list member's email address or contact_id."

Comment: Please read ATTEMPT TO FIX

Comment: You can read about the errors here https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/ - The error you are getting seems to indicate that the resource/member was not found. You may already have deleted it or used a wrong email.

Answer (score 1):

You can check their documentation here: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/methods-parameters/#path-parameters

> When making a call for information about a particular contact, the Marketing API uses the MD5 hash of the lowercase version of the contact’s email address. We use the MD5 hash because it makes it less likely to leak email addresses—these hashes can’t be translated back to an email address, so if your APIs calls were leaked in some manner, your users’ email addresses remain unexposed.

The `subscriber_hash` is the clients email, lowercased and MD5 hashed.

So in your Laravel project you can create the hash by doing something like:

```
md5(strtolower($email));
```

Comment: Please read ATTEMPT TO FIX